# How to add a application pool in iis by command line?

Tags: iis, command-line

I want to create a application pool in IIS by using command line. I don't know the command line to create it. Please help me if you did.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even easier if you use [New-WebAppPool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790585.aspx) from the [Web Server (IIS) Administration Cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx).